# How to plot Integrals Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This integral

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCdk.png]

is suppose to give the result of energy. I'm trying to graph energy as a function of time. I'm trying to use Mathemathica, but I'm not getting the right graph. The graph is suppose to look like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0uXn.jpg]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are showing should actually not produce a graph: the three integrals that are added are all definite integrals and they all produce a number. In other words: all `t`-dependence is integrated out, there is simply nothing to plot, strictly speaking.

However, you can generate the plot in the following way. It is clear that the domain has been cut up into 3 sections, so we define a `Piecewise` function as as the integrant:

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{50 t, t < 1}, {0, 1 <= t < 3}, {50 t - 200, 3 <= t}}]
```

Next, we calculate the integral of this function starting at `t = 0`:

```
fIntegral[t_] = Assuming[Element[t, Reals], Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}]]
```

Note how this integral uses a dummy integration variable `t1` to do the integration from `0` to `t`. This dummy variable drops out when you do the integral and the final result does not depend on `t1`; only on `t`. (BTW: the `Assuming` is necessary to tell Mathematica that `t` is a real number and not something strange like a complex number. If you don't do that, Mathematica tries to be more clever than you need it to be here).

Now you can simply plot the integral and get the plot you needed:

```
Plot[{fIntegral[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[t_] := Integrate[50 \[Tau], {\[Tau], 0, Min[{t, 1}]}] + 
  If[t > 3, Integrate[50 \[Tau] - 200, {\[Tau], 3, Min[{t, 4}]}], 0]
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please expand your answer to explain what your code does and how it answers the OP's question.